# insert 2 lines in a single coloumn cell

Tags: java, sql, jsp

Can any one suggest how to insert two lines in a single cell? I.e., I need to enter the first line and then the second line should start from new line in the single column cell. Suppose I have a column defined as `varchar(100)`, I need to store the string `core java,j2EE will service request` as,
`core java`
`j2EE will service request`

in a single colomn.

When I retrieve back from the database and displayed on a JSP page it should display in two lines.
I am trying to retrieve Japanese content from database and display using jsp. Is Japanese content (which is in utf-8 format)causing any the problem so that `<br />` tag is not parsing as line break.It is coming as `string <br />` when I display it on screen.

Comment: Why would that be a problem? A newline is a character just like any other

Comment: Please fix the markup of your question. What is text, what is code?

Comment: use concat('java',', ','j2EE will service request') while inserting

Comment: Just a quick question, does varchar(100) mean that each cell in the column can store 100 bytes?  -http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: yea. only for example I have taken varchar(100). actually I need to store the lines using newline character

Comment: Read my first comment again. A newline is just a character. You can store a hundred newlines in a varchar100, or a hundred empty lines if you want; the SQL engine Does.Not.Care. From its point of view, there is no such things as "lines".

Answer (score 1):

A newline character (`'\n'`)is still a character, so there's no problem inserting it:

```
Connection conn = ...;
PreparedStatement ps = 
  conn.prepareStatement
  ("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (?)");
ps.setString (1, "j2EE will service request\nin a single coloumn.");
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Notes:

1. Different platforms have different line separators, so depending on how exactly this data is going to be consumed, using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` **may** be more appropriate.
2. For clarity's sake, again, this code omits resource management (e.g., closing the statement) and error-handling code.

Comment: I'm really not sure about using the system's line separator. If your data is meant to be used by third parties, it is in fact more portable to use `\n` alone.

Comment: @fge I can imagine such a usecase, thanks. As always, context is king - I'll edit my note accordingly.

Comment: @Mureinik: I am still getting the issue. \n is not parsed as a new line character in a jsp page. I am getting \n as it is when I display it on my jsp page. ultimately I need to display on a jsp page.

Comment: @ChandanDN If printing to JSP is the issue (BTW: why wasn't mentioned in the OP), you need an HTML newline specificer - just use `<br/>` instead of `\n`.

Comment: I tried putting <br /> also. still <br /> is not parsed as a break to line.Iamtrying Japanese content to retrieve from database and  display. Is Japanese content (which is in utf-8 format)causing any the problem??

Comment: @ChandanDN it's impossible to answer like this. Please edit your question (or open a new one) with **all** the relevant details and with the **exact** problem.